# Reverse has_one / belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a page layout application that has spreads and pages. Each spread contains two pages (a left page and a right page).

The database looks like this:

```
create_table :spreads do |t|
  ...
  t.references :left_page
  t.references :right_page
  ...
end

create_table :pages do |t|
  # No foreign keys
end
```

Semantically, two pages belong to a spread, so it would make sense to set up the models as follows:

```
class Spread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :left_page, :class_name => 'Page'
  has_one :right_page, :class_name => 'Page'
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spread
end
```

But, since the foreign keys live in the spreads table, Rails seems to demand the reverse:

```
class Spread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left_page, :class_name => 'Page'
  belongs_to :right_page, :class_name => 'Page'
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :spread
end
```

Whenever I run into something like this in Rails, it makes me think I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way. Is that the case or do I just live with code that doesn't quite read clearly?

Comment: as a note to followers, has_one and belongs_to are basically reciprocals and you basically have to specify them both [odd] http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**short answer:**

it depends on your business rules.

**longer answer:**

It is a schema design issue, not really a rails issue...

Since you already decided that the foreign keys MUST be in the `spreads` table, it means you had good reasons to do so (right ?). `belongs_to` only reflects this structure.

Sure, you could have placed those FKS on the `pages` table. Functionaly, it (more or less) changes nothing... for now. But how will it work when you implement callbacks? How easy will it be to manipulate your objects ?

*This is an architecture decision, and only you can decide.*

Now, IMHO, it seems that your design is right. This structure holds more information in itself that would the other solution : your `spread` object will *always* have 0-1 left page and 0-1 right page; not only the fact that a spread has *at most* 2 pages is reflected in this structure, but each FK also reflects a *quality* of the association (*left* or *right* page). So i would stick with this solution, even if it "reads weird".

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that I'm on the right track. I get that it's a schema design issue. It's just that whenever I do something that doesn't quite jive with "the rails way", I begin to question myself...perhaps a little too much at times. Thanks!

Comment: Just between you and me, i alway found that association macro were poorly named. To me, belongs_to should be named "references" as in the schema statements (with all that follows: "referenced_by_many", "referenced_by_one"...). It would be much more clear and reflect accurately the actual structure... YMMV